# Need help to reload WKWebView from tabbed navigation in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make this reload when a user clicks on the tab. I tried a simple reload but didn't work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var TabOne: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
    TabOne.load(urlRequest)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the reload code into the `viewWillAppear(_:)`

as `viewDidLoad()` will only be called once in the view controller life cycle, while `viewWillAppear(_:)` will be called every time the view is going to appear on the screen.

Comment: Thank you. This is what ended up working for me. `import UIKit
import WebKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var TabOne: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
        TabOne.load(urlRequest)
    }
}`

Comment: you're welcome, please accept answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that ended up working.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TabOne: WKWebView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
        TabOne.load(urlRequest)
    }
}
```